# Node edit form shows cached or previous title while editing node, after updating node?

Tags: 7, nodes, caching

When I update a node the revision show changes in values when we see diff but after updating node when I edit node again in node edit from it shows old value ie: cached value.

When I flush all cache then the updated value start appearing in node edit form.

In site no page cache is enabled, no block cache is enabled. But we are using **memcache**

This does not happens always but starts happening when cache not cleared for few hours but after clearing cache it starts working.

Please suggest what kind of cache is effecting values while editing node titles.

I am using modules as well [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) and [entity_translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation)

In my views there is no cache and I am using template file for views nid in which I fetch titles like below which also shows cached version :

```
$link = node_load($nid);
$link->title_field['en'][0]['value']  // English value title
$link->title_field['fr'][0]['value']  // French value of title
```

Should I try like this to get rid of cache:

```
$link = node_load($nid,null,true); // setting true
```

Please suggest, I have been trying and searching from long time but not able to find solution. It seems like problems with memcache.

**Minimum cache lifetime = none**

**EDIT:** seems kind of some similar problem [Need to flush cache after node translation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37345/need-to-flush-cache-after-node-translation?rq=1)

**TRIED SOLUTION and this is of no help :**

```
function custom_module_node_update($node) {
  $nodeurl = url('node/'. $node->nid);
  cache_clear_all($nodeurl, 'cache_page');
  cache_clear_all("field:node:$node->nid", 'cache_field');
}
```

I am not sure this will help in this case or not or while updating translation of node. Please suggest!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to below for cache and removed memcached completely. All problems solved with this.

https://www.drupal.org/project/redis

https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache

Thanks!